# Why are variables not allowed in alternative patterns?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Often you have "symmetric" matches and want to write things like:

```
def g(p:(Int,Int)) = p match {
  case (10,n) | (n,10) => println(n)
  case _ => println("nope")
}
```

This is not allowed, but if every alternative has *the same variables* with *the same types*, this shouldn't be a problem, as it could be translated to separate cases:

```
def g(p:(Int,Int)) = p match {
  case (10,n) => println(n)
  case (n,10) => println(n)
  case _ => println("nope")
}
```

So why do we have this restriction?

Comment: Coming from OCaml, I really miss these convenient pattern-matching features.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Likely because it would take some time to implement and that time is better spent elsewhere. It would also unnecessarily add to the complexity of the language and its compiler. As you already mentioned, the problem can easily be avoided. One other way to avoid the problem is to write a custom extractor:

```
object ThisOrThat {
  def unapply(p:(Int,Int)):Option[Int] = p match {
    case (10, n) => Some(n)
    case (n, 10) => Some(n)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you have a lot of matching patterns, not just two.

Comment: then you write a custom extractor as shown in my edited answer

Comment: Kim actually gave the real reason, not just a good one. I had this discussion with Burak Emir (former maintainer of Scala pattern matching and the person behind scala extractors' implementation) a couple of years ago and Kim's answer matches Burak's thought. Well done Kim! You got my +1 ;)

Comment: @Mirco: I tried to implement a generic Or extractor class that gets other extractors as constructr arguments, but this failed because there is no Trait implemented by all extractors and one can't access type parameters inside structural types. Any plans to change either? Then one could do this in a library...

Comment: @Kim if you have a workable idea to define generic or-extractor I'd suggest you to post it in the scala mailing list. I'd definitely be interested :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it would be tedious to implement... There's a [feature suggestion](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SUGGEST-25) from way back.

The obvious workarounds are to either define a function for the result, and call it from separate `case`s (better for simple patters), or to define a custom extractor for the alternative pattern, as Kim suggested (better when it is nested inside a pattern you'd rather not have to duplicate).

Either way, it ends up more verbose and harder to read than if it were supported by the language though, so hopefully someone will implement it eventually.