# Alternative pattern matching with variable binding?

Tags: scala

I try to implement an equivalence relation over terms which I also would like to match against some patterns. However my relation is symmetric and therefore, the pattern matching must reflect this too.

Have a look at the following example:

```
abstract class Term
case class Constructor(txt:String) extends Term
case class Variable(txt:String) extends Term

case class Equality(t1:Term, t2:Term)

def foobar(e:Equality) = e match {
    case Equality(Variable(x),Constructor(y)) => "do something rather complicated with x and y"
    case Equality(Constructor(y),Variable(x)) => "do it all over again"
}
```

Infact I would like to do something like this

```
def foobar(e:Equality) = e match {
    case Equality(Variable(x),Constructor(y)) | Equality(Constructor(y),Variable(x)) 
        => "yeah! this time we need to write the code only one time ;-)"
}
```

However, as noted e.g. in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6561836/why-are-variables-not-allowed-in-alternative-patterns), this is not allowed. Does someone have a nice solution for this kind of problem? Any help/pointer is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own unapply method like this:

```
object CVEquality {
  def unapply(e: Equality): Option(String, String) = e match {
    case Equality(Variable(v), Constructor(c)) => Some(c -> v)
    case Equality(Constructor(c), Variable(v)) => Some(c -> v)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
def foobar(e:Equality) = e match {
    case CVEquality(c, v) => "do something rather complicated with c and v"
}
```

The easiest way is to create method for `something rather complicated`:

```
def complicated(c: String, v: String) = "do something rather complicated with c and v"

def foobar(e:Equality) = e match {
    case Equality(Variable(x),Constructor(y)) => complicated(y, x)
    case Equality(Constructor(y),Variable(x)) => complicated(y, x)
}
```

Comment: I suspected that I have to do it like described in your answer but hoped there is an easy solution :D Anyway I like your second idea more because I hope that the compiler makes use of back tracking, i.e. produce more efficient code if there are dozens of other case statements.