# Extract same value type from pattern matching "or" case

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

This must be possible, yet I'm unable to find any examples or guidance online...

I am trying to extract a variable from an `Either` return where `Left` can have an `Exception` case class with the value I want OR a `Right` with the value I want.

Definitions:

```
def findInnerObj(innerObjId: String): Either[InnerObjNotFoundException, (OuterObj, InnerObj)] = ???

case class InnerObjNotFoundException(outer: OuterObj) extends Exception
```

Usage:

```
findInnerObj(innerObjId) match {
  case Left(InnerObjNotFoundException(x)) | Right((x, _)) =>
    // do something with x <-- ATM, compiler: "Cannot resolve symbol x"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pattern alternatives with name binding are not supported, you can do it like this.

```
val innerObj = findInnerObj(innerObjId) match {
  case Left(InnerObjNotFoundException(x)) => x
  case Right((x, _)) => x
}
// do something with innerObj
```

Comment: My wording was off otherwise I would have found the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428685/alternative-pattern-matching-with-variable-binding